# How to get image matrix from axes content

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to get the content of a contourf plot as an image matrix? I want rasterize only the content, not the axes, labels and the empty space of the entire figure.

My goal is to overlay a transparent, colored contour plot over a grayscale image and I don't see another way, since MATLAB has only one colormap per figure.

Comment: Could you convert the image matrix to a rgb grayscale image (i.e. n x m x 3) and then use imshow(RGB) to show this image? This should stop the grayscale image relying on the colourmap.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so, since the contour plot should use a jet colormap which would make the grayscale image unrecognizable.

Comment: See my answer below - as your background image is grayscale it is possible to plot that in true colour, and use the figure's colourmap for the contourf plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html)  and [`frame2im`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/frame2im.html)

Example from the `frame2im` documentation:

```
Create and capture an image using getframe and frame2im:

peaks                      %Make figure
f = getframe;              %Capture screen shot
[im,map] = frame2im(f);    %Return associated image data 
if isempty(map)            %Truecolor system
  rgb = im;
else                       %Indexed system
  rgb = ind2rgb(im,map);   %Convert image data
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the question, but this is how I think you could achieve your goal:

```
%# load in grayscale image
gray_im =  rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));

%# converting n x m grey image to n x m x 3 rgb gray image
rgb_gray_im = cat( 3, gray_im, gray_im, gray_im );

%# displaying this image
imshow( rgb_gray_im );

%# plotting contourf on top with arbitrary colourmap
hold on
h = axes('position', [0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2]);
z = peaks;
contourf(h, z, [min(z(:)), -6 : 8]);
```

Which gives the result:

[image]

The figure's colourmap is being used for the contourf plot. The background image is not relying on a colourmap, and is instead being displayed in truecolour - i.e. each pixel is being displayed as an RGB value defined in rgb_gray_im.

There are also other ways of getting around the MATLAB colourmap restrictions: see for example [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/07/24/using-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure/) or [these answers](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-GNRWEH/index.html).

Comment: See some answers here: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/fbbb5df8d9c2dcd9?pli=1